# Google map navigation using Google Maps API v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps API v2 in my app. I want to enable navigation feature in my app. I have read other posts which start an `Intent` and open stock Google Maps application to show navigation. But I want to display the navigation inside my application(`SupportMapFragment` that I have used) only. How can I implement that?

This code works well but it starts an `Intent` :

```
Intent NavIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + incAddress));
    startActivity(NavIntent);
```

Answer (score 4):

there is no way to show the google maps app navigation in your app, it is a completely different app. the only way you can display navigation in your app is to use `Google Directions API` and plot the route on your map but then you dont have the turn by turn directions.

I created a library that uses the google directions api and its easy to use if you want to try it out.

https://github.com/tyczj/MapNavigator